# Unable to connect to moquette in aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, mqtt, mosquitto, hivemq, moquette

I am new to MQTT and have been trying to implement MQTT MOquette on AWS EC2, i tried the configuration and installation of broker on my machine and was able to connect and test it from client, however when i do the same from Aws EC2 instance i can see the ports 1883, 8080 listening to 0.0.0.0 ip address but when i connect from client i am not able to connect.

While configuring host in local machine i provided 0.0.0.0 for host and ports 1883, 8080 and on AWS server i provided the private ip for host and ports are 1883, 8080. I have added rules in security groups to allow tcp on 1883 & 8080.

My question is what should be the host value i should use on AWS like private ip or aws url like 'ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' and what would be the url from which i could access broker from client like 'tcp://ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' or the IP

What would i be doing wrong here ?? stuck with this issue

Thanks All

Comment: if you are dealing with port, you should use Elastic IP.

Comment: ec2 instance already has public api so Elastic IP may not be required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some search i was finally able to solve the issue, i was always checking for security groups where everything was right but i missed adding rule in ec2 instance firewall for the ports 1883, 8080. Once its done i was able to connect to the broker from external clients.

Thanks for all who tried to help.